# Explore @odata.NextLink

Tags: powershell

I have this as variables:
[image]

I need to access @odata.nextLink; I tried calling it by doing this with no luck:

```
$messages2 = Invoke-RestMethod $messages.odatanextLink -Credential $cred
```

I also tried with this and it failed:

```
$messages2 = Invoke-RestMethod $messages.@odata.nextLink -Credential $cred
```

The code before that is:

```
$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages" 
$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

$messageQuery = "" + $url + "?`$select=Id&`$filter=HasAttachments eq true and DateTimeReceived ge " + $date
$messages = Invoke-RestMethod $messageQuery -Credential $cred 

foreach ($message in $messages.value) 
{
```

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you can safely qualify the member name with quotes:

```
$messages2 = Invoke-RestMethod $messages.'@odata.nextLink' -Credential $cred
```