# Trouble using the Reports in Microsoft Graph - getOneDriveUsageAccountDetail

Tags: rest, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to pull data for a getOneDriveUsageAccountDetail REST GET from PowerShell. The trouble is that by default it will only return 200 items, I've managed to get it to return 10000 items, I think this is a hard limit. But I need to get all the items, or be able to query the report for one user, or a batch of users. This doesn't appear to be possible.

I've found I can add `&%24top=10000` to my URI to return 10000 results.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getonedriveusageaccountdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0

The only parameters are period and date.

I have an Initialize-Authorization function to create an $script:APIHeader to store an access token. This works fine.

This is the function I'm using to generate the report.

```
Function Get-GraphOneDriveUsageAccountDetail {
    $result = (Invoke-RestMethod `
            -Method get `
            -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOneDriveUsageAccountDetail(period='D180')?%24format=application%2Fjson&%24top=10000" `
            -ContentType 'application/json' `
            -Headers $script:APIHeader `
            -ErrorAction Stop).value
    return $result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Graph endpoints return [paged data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?toc=.%2Fref%2Ftoc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0):

> Some queries against Microsoft Graph return multiple pages of data either due to server-side paging or due to the use of the `$top` query parameter to specifically limit the page size in a request. When a result set spans multiple pages, Microsoft Graph returns an `@odata.nextLink` property in the response that contains a URL to the next page of results.

You need to follow the `nextLink` in the result to retrieve the next page (the last page is the first result without a `nextLink`).

Comment: Thanks @marc-lafleur. I think I have it working. But I think I've swamped the server as I'm now getting `The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests` errors, but that's my fault. I also found this previous question that helped. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282488/explore-odata-nextlink)

Answer (score 0):

This was my final code:

```
Function Get-GraphOneDriveUsageAccountDetail {
    $AccountDetail = Invoke-RestMethod `
            -Method get `
            -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOneDriveUsageAccountDetail(period='D180')?%24format=application%2Fjson&%24top=10000" `
            -ContentType 'application/json' `
            -Headers $script:APIHeader `
            -ErrorAction Stop
            $result = $AccountDetail.value
While($AccountDetail.'@odata.nextLink')
    {
            Write-Verbose "Next Link $($AccountDetail.'@odata.nextLink')" -Verbose
            $AccountDetail = Invoke-RestMethod `
            -Method get `
            -Uri $AccountDetail.'@odata.nextLink' `
            -ContentType 'application/json' `
            -Headers $script:APIHeader `
            -ErrorAction Stop
            $result += $AccountDetail.value
    }
    return $result
}
```